# How can I make the string split based on the specified keywords in Flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want to make the string split based on the specified keywords (not case sensitive).

Can anyone guide me, thank you.

Example, the source:

```
Hello world, Susan;
```

If I specify the keyword as `world`, I want to get:

```
['Hello ', 'world', ', Susan;']
```

If I specify the keyword as `Hello`, I want to get:

```
['Hello', ' world, Susan;']
```

If I specify the keyword as `su`, I want to get:

```
['Hello world, ', 'Su', 'san'];
```

If I specify the keyword as `o`, I want to get:

```
['Hell', 'o', ' w', 'o', 'rld, Susan;']
```

I have tried `String.split`, but it does not work for me, because the result of `split` ignores the keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main() {
  String test = "Ni hao, wo shi zhu, ni bang zhu wo xie regexp.";
  String delimeter = "zhu";
  String regexpStr = "(?<=PlaceHolder)|(?=PlaceHolder)".replaceAll("PlaceHolder", delimeter);
  RegExp splitter = new RegExp(regexpStr, caseSensitive: false);

  List<String> parts = test.split(splitter);   
  for (int i = 0 ; i < parts.length; i++) {
    print (parts[i]);
  }
}
```

我在[DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)上跑了没问题。

Comment: Consider using `RegExp.escape(delimiter)` in the `regexpStr` to avoid characters which means something in a `RegExp` from being inserted verbatim. (Ofcourse, it it's deliberately allowing a `RegExp` as delimiter, then the current code is fine).
There is also an issue with overlapping delimiters. If `delimiter` is `abab`, then the string `cabababc` will be splint into `["c", "cab", "abc", "c"]` which has too many `c`'s.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to split,

```
splitTheWord() {
    String data = "Hello world, Susan;";
    // here use the word with which you want to split.
    String word = "world";
    List<String> splitWords = data.split(word);
    print("Length : ${splitWords.length}");
    for (int i = 0; i < splitWords.length; i++) {
      print("current word : ${i} : ${splitWords[i]}");
    }
  }
```

Comment: This does not work for me, because the result of `split` ignores the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

`String.split` splits on a pattern.  A pattern can be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
String splitString = "Hello world, Susan;";

String splitword = "Su"?.toLowerCase();

print("Split ===> ${splitString?.toLowerCase().replaceAll(splitword, "*$splitword*").split("*")}");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write my own function for this:

```
List<String> splitAround(Pattern pattern, String input) {
  var i = 0;
  var result = <String>[];
  for (var m in pattern.allMatches(input)) {
    result
      ..add(input.substring(i, m.start))  // Or only do this if i > m.start
      ..add(m[0]);
    i = m.end;
  }
  result.add(input.substring(i));
  return result;
}
```

This code should collect both the parts between matches and the matches themselves,
and it will avoid overlapping matches.

It doesn't do case-insensitive matching, so if you want that, you should wrap your original split string as `RegExp(RegExp.escape(string), caseSensitive: false)` before calling the function.